# How to specify a layout of a wall post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using facebook opengraph for sharing my users stories on facebook.

I am trying to create the following layout for my app's wallpost : [Figure 1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/441/wantb.png/) 
All I am able to get is this : [Figure 2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/postdeb.png/)
I selected the Item layout for my action in the opengraph configurations, however, the captions are always below the image.

How do I achieve the layout as in figure 1?

Comment: so you want to post this as a image right?.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy Yes, the image on the left, and captions to its right. Can I use the entire width (image+captions) as an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. Facebook uses the new layout, ie. the one in figure2, for images which are larger than 200x200pixels. And, facebook insists that we use images larger than 200x200pixels, because it looks better in aggregations. However, if you still want the layout as in figure1, then you need to use images smaller than 200x200pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook may have changed this again, but I found that images need to be 600x315px to display as the larger version - see [Facebook's information about this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images)